# swift 4 Core Motion Magnetometer magnetometerUpdateInterval doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion, magnetometer

I'm not sure what I'm missing, the update interval setting doesn't seem to do anything. Whether I set it to 3.0 or 0.3, my numbers update a few times a second. I don't see CPU going up or down too much, so it doesn't seem like iOS clipping it...? Latest Xcode and Swift.

```
import UIKit
import CoreMotion

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var xlabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ylabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var zlabel: UILabel!

let manager = CMMotionManager()
let queue = OperationQueue()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    func setLabel(field: CMMagneticField) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.xlabel.text = "\(floor(field.x))"
        self.ylabel.text = "\(floor(field.y))"
        self.zlabel.text = "\(floor(field.z))"}
    }

    if manager.isMagnetometerAvailable {
    manager.magnetometerUpdateInterval = 3.0
        manager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(using: CMAttitudeReferenceFrame.xArbitraryCorrectedZVertical,
            to: queue, withHandler: {(data: CMDeviceMotion?, error: Error?) in
            if let field = data?.magneticField.field {
                setLabel(field: field)}
    })} else {
        print("I guess there's nothing there")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you testing this on the device, or are you using one of the simulators?

Comment: the values of the property magnetometerUpdateInterval might be capped (e.g. depending on the hardware). See here for more info https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmmotionmanager/1616089-magnetometerupdateinterval

Comment: Using it on a real device, iPhone 8. The program shows values that seem like the Earth's magnetic field lines, plus big numbers if I stand next to the refrigerator. I can wave a magnet near it and it goes crazy. But, I can't seem to control the update frequency. Thanks